# Does the comma prevent "which" from referring to the 2018 number in "in 2019 — more than the total in 2018, which surpassed the record of 2017"?

Tags: meaning, commas

> Despite a strong consumer economy, physical retailers closed more than 9,000 stores in 2019 — more than the total in 2018, **which** surpassed the record of 2017. Already this year, retailers have announced more than 1,200 more intended closings, including 125 Macy’s stores.

Is it only because of comma there that "which" can not refer to the number in 2018?

Answer (score 1):

> Despite a strong consumer economy, physical retailers closed more than 9,000 stores in 2019 — more than the total in 2018, which surpassed the record of 2017.

I take this as meaning that 9,000 stores closed in 2019; that 2019 had more stores closing than 2018; that 2018 had more closures than 2017; and that 2017 was a "record" -- that is, 2017 had more closures than any previous year. The removal of the comma after "2018" would not in my view change that meaning at all. The word "which" refers back to "the total in 2018"m the nearest plausible antecedent. To read this as saying that 2019 had a higher total than either 2018 or 2017, but 2017's total was higher than 2018 would be -- odd. If that was the intended meaning, the sentence should have been significantly rephrased.

I disagree with the statement that "Em-dashes are probably also best avoided in formal writing." Indeed I think Em-dashes are more likely to be used in formal writing than in casual writing. They can be confusing, however.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand there isn't a definite grammar rule for what it should refer to,  common knowledge or more context is the way to read it.

Comment: Em-dashes are maybe best avoided unless you really know how to use them; which is a different rule to saying they should be avoided always.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not. I would just ditch the em dash and turn it into two separate sentences instead to enhance its readability.

There were a few other issues as well.

I think it might be best rewritten as:

> Despite a strong consumer economy, physical retailers *have* closed more than 9,000 stores in 2019. This was more than the total in 2018 which had also surpassed 2017's record. *So far* this year, retailers have announced *their intention to close* 1,200 more stores, *125 of which are Macy's stores*.

Another thing I want to point it is how there shouldn't be a space between the em dash and the words. An example of the correct format:

> The car was a such beat-up old thing—I was surprised it even started up at all.

Em-dashes are probably also best avoided in formal writing.

Comment: I don't get it. The original sentence meant 9,000 in 2019 is more than 2017, but didn't say 2018 is also more than 2017.  You changed the meaning.

Comment: @wtdark I don't think that's right. The original says that 2019 had more closings than 2018 and that 2018 had more than 2017.

Comment: @user34258, "Coresight Research says over 8,500 stores have closed this year, 47% more than last year and ahead of the record 8,000 or so that shut down in 2017."

Comment: @wtdark I was referring to the quote in the question; my mistake if it's not the true original. The quote in question appears says that 2018 had more than 2017.

Comment: no, if it means what you said, it should be the way Hsu wrote without comma in between.

Comment: @wtdark I'm confused. Wasn't it your intention that 'which should correspond to 2018'? It was why I wrote it that way. I thought you wanted to change the meaning?

Comment: When I first read it, for some reason, I thought the sentence said 2019 had more closings than 2018 and 2017. But now that I read it again, it feels like it could be referring to either and it leans more towards it being a comparison between 2018 and 17. Whether or not your comma is there, it could be read either way. Please try to be more clear about your question.

Comment: I wrote it without a comma because it's unnecessary in my sentences unless you want a pause between the two parts. It wouldn't change the meaning at all, whether I added it or not.

Comment: @Hsu reading class teacher said "which" should refer to 2019 but didn't explain why it is that in grammar way.  I guessed it is the comma so I asked to confirm. Sorry for the confusion caused here.